# CVS header keywords not replaced

Tags: header, replace, cvs, keyword

I have a unique problem with few of my files where the header information (Author/RCSFile/Date etc) is not automatically replaced when I commit my changes using Eclipse.

It comes back to blank:

```
######################## COPYRIGHT ################################
#
#       $RCSfile$
#          Owner: My Company
#      $Revision$
#          $Date$
#
#   Last $Author$
#
#    Description: Some description
#
####################################################################
```

Any idea why it would so? Out of 500 files I have only issue for 6 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword substitution is configurable for each file (so that binaries aren't corrupted when you check them out).  Do a `cvs log -h` on the offending files and check the "`keyword substitution`" line.  The default is

```
keyword substitution: kv
```

Compare against other files that don't have this problem.

If that's not it, could there be non-printable characters in the file?  Try `cat -A filename` if your system supports it, or `cat -v filename` if it doesn't (pipe the output to `head` or your favorite pager).

EDIT: Looks like the keyword substitution line was the problem.  Use `cvs admin` to fix it.  (I though it would be better to have this information in the answer rather than just in the comment.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw the output and its just "k" the other files which dont have an issue is giving "kv". How can I fix this?